# Mapping two xsd files by updating values of its respective java objects

Tags: java, spring, xsd, dozer, mapstruct

I have a working scenario for mapping/transforming objects in java in the following format

source.xsd -> convert to java objects -> consider request parameters -> update source objects -> Map/Transform to destination objects (which were created by converting destination.xsd) -> call a webservice to obtain the values.

Achieved solutions:

1. Mapping using Translator Pattern (Example: https://richhewlett.com/2010/06/11/a-useful-entity-translator-pattern-object-mapper-template/)
2. Used DozerMapper and Mapstruct to transform the objects

Kindly suggest better Solutions by considering scenarios:

1. The number of xsd mappings is getting increased with numerous parameters and it is difficult to understand for the new project members as it would be tightly coupled.
2. Instead of converting xsd to objects, is there any framework to map one xsd with another xsd by updating its relative values dynamically and then convert final xsd to java objects for calling respective service.